# What does "lit" mean, in The Cat in the Hat

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

*The Cat in the Hat*, by Dr Seuss contains the following:

> I do not like this said the fish as he lit. I do not like it, not
>   one little bit.

What on earth does **lit** mean in this context?

A guess is that it means **alighted**, considering the fish has landed in the teapot.

Perhaps it's a typo?

Thanks to my 5-year old daughter for spotting this, somehow I never noticed it myself.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's an alternate past participle for _[alight](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alit)_.

Comment: @BillFranke can you find a reference for that? I can only find mention of _alit_ and _alighted_ but I don't have access to good dictionary.

Comment: @terdon: Here's a link to [thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/alit?s=b) for **alit**. You can trust thesaurus.com. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alit) also has an entry. M-W #rd Unabridged says: "Main Entry:alit = past of  ALIGHT" & "Main Entry:1alight
Pronunciation:**l*t, usu -d.+V
Function:intransitive verb 
Inflected Form:alighted  \-*d.*d, -*t*d\ ; or sometimes alit  \**lit\ ; alighted ; alighting ; alights 
Etymology:Middle English alighten to alight, alighten, from Old English *l*htan, from *- (perfective prefix) + l*htan to alight, lighten * more at ABEAR, LIGHT"

Comment: @BillFranke thanks but I see no mention of _lit_ (although they do suggest _light_ as a synonym) in either of the links you offered. Your M-W seems to mention it though, assuming that _**lit_ is a reference to _lit_.

Comment: http://m.dictionary.com/d/?q=lit

Comment: @terdon: Check out MετάEd's link. It has just what you want.

Comment: It's pretty standard to use _light/lit_ to refer to flying creatures like insects or birds, and metaphorically to people or animals flitting around rapidly.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I am looking for a reference supporting the use of _lit_ as a past participle of _alight_ rather than _light_.

Comment: Well, when people say _light_ instead of _alight_, you can call both of them variant forms of _alight_, right?

Answer (score 4):

It is the past of *light*, a verb which has almost fallen out of use, but means the same as *alight*.

The OED says *s.v.* 'light'

> II. To descend. *Cf*. alight *v*.1

with an example from William Morris in 1868: "While from the horse he lit adown." (I imagine it was a deliberate archaism by Morris).