# Meaning of "lit" seemingly undiscussed as of yet

Tags: american-english, north-american-english

In [the Wikipedia article on the Skull and Bones secret society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skull_and_Bones) a quote attributed to Lanny Davis is given like so: "If the society had a good year, this is what the 'ideal' group will consist of: [...] a Chairman of the Lit". There are [a](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114934/what-does-lit-mean-in-the-cat-in-the-hat) [couple](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297133/whats-the-origin-of-lit) of questions about "lit" (lowercase) here already, but I couldn't find out what "Lit" (uppercase) in this context could mean. Is it possibly a place in Yale?

Comment: This is more about culture and history and less about English, so it's likely off-topic here, but from context *The Lit* has to be some kind of institution, likely a prestigious one, likely related to literature. For example, from [this Questia article](https://www.questia.com/read/1G1-480269138/tv-star-hails-moves-to-improve-lit-phil-access): *Paul Gailiunas, chairman of **the Lit & Phil (full name: the Literary and Philosophical Society of Newcastle upon Tyne)**, said there had been a plan to improve access to the building for at least 20 years.*

Comment: "The Lit" is [The Yale Literary Magazine](http://yalelitmag.com/)

Comment: @StoneyB, if you could make that an answer, I could accept it. Dan, sorry for the off-topic ... I couldn't have known before. I still think it's useful, at least to us non-native speakers. FWIW, if the quote had saiid "The Lit" then I think I would have been able to recognize it better.

Comment: @StoneyB There's a vacuum here and you might be the best one to fill it

Comment: @MetaEd As you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Lit" is the informal name of [*The Yale Literary Magazine*](http://yalelitmag.com/); in fact, if you follow that link the first thing you see is "Welcome to the Lit". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yale_Literary_Magazine) says that it is

> ... the oldest literary magazine in the United States and publishes poetry and fiction by Yale undergraduates twice per academic year.

Comment: Thanks! :) Also interesting that you use "twice per academic year" as opposed to "once per semester" (which is the lingo used at all the European universities I know).

Comment: @RainerVerteidiger I agree: that's Wikipedia, not me. But The Lit's own blurb is worse than either of these: "... a **semesterly** print magazine that showcases the creative work of Yale undergraduates." I cringe.

Answer (score -3):

Merriam Webster dictionary says "1918"

Here's the link also

https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/lit-meaning-origin

Here's the definition

> > We walked into the vamp's house. We all got lit and had a hell of a time. —John McGavock Grider, War Birds: Diary of an Unknown Aviator, 1918
>
> This particular use of lit comes from the original use of lit to refer to something that is illumined or has light shining on it (from the past tense of the verb light). It sounds like a semantic stretch, but it’s not: lit and lit up are often used to refer to the look on someone’s face when they are suddenly made happy by something, and there’s no denying that many people feel or look similarly happy when under the influence.
>
> Though the “drunk” meaning of lit has a pedigree stretching back over a century, it is still considered slang: it doesn’t have the same sort of all-purpose use that drunk does, and it still shows up generally in very informal settings, like speech and rap lyrics. In fact, the “intoxicated” sense of lit has had a resurgence of use among a new generation of youth thanks in no small part to rap.
>
> Rap has also given us a new meaning of lit. In the last ten or so years, lit has transitioned from being applied to the act of intoxicating ("gonna get lit") to the environment of those who are lit ("party's lit"). The wildness of such parties has led to lit gaining the meaning “exciting,” as well as a broader meaning along the lines of “excellent” (“Leslie Jones's commentary on the Olympics was lit"). We have evidence of the “exciting” and “excellent” meanings way back to 2004, and earlier use is likely—slang is often spoken long before it’s written down. This extended meaning of lit is a favorite on social media like Twitter

Comment: The answer is ‘‘42’’,  but what is the question?

Comment: None of these meanings fit the context given in the question. In any case, this MW article was already mentioned in [one of the answers to a question OP linked to](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/297177/191178).

Comment: This answer could be improved by going beyond quoting a reference. Try to showing that this is actually the intended meaning in the quotation in the question.